# Has the phrase 'Beam me up Scotty' been used in TAS or any movies?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-reboot, star-trek-tas, star-trek-movies

As most Trekkies know, the popular phrase 'Beam me up Scotty' was never actually spoken in any of The Original Series.  As any good Trekkie knows though, *TOS* wasn't the only material where we had Scotty along with the original crew; we've got *The Animated Series* and the movies as well!  So, **has the phrase 'Beam me up Scotty' ever been used in *TAS* or any of the movies?**  I will include the 2009 reboot.

Comment: For fun, click [this youtube search link](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beam+me+up+scotty)

Comment: Takei says it in this video; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KyUQCqjcEU

Comment: Weren't there also radio plays featuring the original series cast as voice talent?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## No

But we have come *very* close.  The closest is probably *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*:

> KIRK: Thank you, ...for everything. **Scotty, beam me up!**

Other notable instances of being very close include:

- Assignment: Earth (*TOS*)

  > KIRK: Yes, I think we could say that. **Two to beam up, Scotty.**
- The Lorelei Signal (*TAS*)

  > KIRK [OC]: **Beam us up, Scotty.**
- The Savage Curtain (*TOS*)

  > KIRK: **Scotty, beam us up** fast.
- The Infinite Vulcan (*TAS*)

  > KIRK: Kirk to Enterprise. **Beam us up, Scotty**
- The Mark Of Gideon (*TOS*)

  > KIRK: Mister Spock, we have a patient for Doctor McCoy. **Have Scotty beam us up.**
- *Star Trek: Generations*

  > KIRK: **Beam them out of there, Scotty**
- Arena (*TOS*)

  > KIRK: Cover! Kirk to Enterprise, lock on transporters. **Beam us up.**
- The Paradise Syndrome (*TOS*)

  > SPOCK: In the time it's taken me to explain the problem, the asteroid has moved from here to here. The longer we delay, the less the likelihood of being able to divert it. **Beam us up, Mister Scott**
- The Squire of Gothos (*TOS*)

  > KIRK: **Beam me up, Mister Spock**. We're free to go.

(That last one is just frustrating!)

Comment: what exactly is TAS?

Comment: @Thomas [The Animated Series](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Animated_Series)

Comment: aaah that is why the shortcut seemed familiar. tnx!

Comment: There's a few *Beam **us** up, Scotty* in there - changing the "us" to "me" just makes it individual rather than a group.