# Origin of 'Beam Me Up Scotty'

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

All good Trekkies know that, despite [coming very close](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/103742/22917), nobody uttered the exact phrase 'Beam Me Up Scotty'.  It's become something of an iconic phrase for *Star Trek* despite its notable absence from canon.

**What is the origin of the phrase 'Beam me up Scotty?'**

Comment: Inspired by Praxis' great question about [Scotty's nickname](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/132346/22917)

Comment: @amaranth Do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can find no single origin point for this never-uttered catchphrase, but I would hazard that it's a natural mutation of several similar phrases, the closest being a command directed at Spock instead of Scotty:

> **KIRK:** ***Beam me up, Mister Spock.***  (From "The Squire of Gothos")

This could easily have become blurred with the various forms of this command issued to Scotty, such as

> **KIRK:** ***Scotty, beam us up fast!*** (From "The Savage Curtain")

etc., as well as a couple instances of

> **KIRK:** ***Beam us up, Scotty***

coming to us by way of *The Animated Series* (for example, as heard in "The Infinite Vulcan").

The earliest instance of "Beam me up, Scotty" I can find in print is in Volume 79 of ***The Aeronautical Journal***, published in 1975:

> ...cliffs, fire, forest or mountain is most probably some form of transporter device such as that used by Captain Kirk and the crew of the starship "Enterprise" — **a sort of "beam me up Scotty" routine**. However as this is still in the realms of fantasy...

([Source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=w0dWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Beam+me+up+Scotty%22&dq=%22Beam+me+up+Scotty%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y))

That this is the origin of the phrase is possible but highly unlikely — it almost certainly existed orally amongst the public in the late 60s during the run of *TOS* itself.

Comment: Did you try Google nGram as well?

Comment: @DVK-in-exile : Yep, that's what led me to the Google Books link.  (nGram is great!) :-)